# HTTP get request to LocalHost on Java

Tags: java, soapui

I'm trying to learn a bit of Java and readthe documentation for the httpClient method since I'm trying to make a call to an endpoint created with Soap UI.

I'm just trying to obtain a response the JSON object but for some reason I keep getting an empty response and a 404 status code. I've been tinkering with it a bit but I can't seem to find the problem.

Here's my code

```
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

public class App {

    private static final String GET_API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/balance?acctnum=1234567";

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .header( "accept", "application/json")
                .uri(URI.create(GET_API_URL))
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println("status:" + response.statusCode());
        System.out.println("response:" + response.body());
    }
}
```

both the system.out are being hit but as mentioned the first one returns status 404 and the second one returns "response:     ".
Any suggestions?

Comment: As application referred by `GET_API_URL` running in your system? Are you able to hit the http://localhost:8080/balance?acctnum=1234567 via browser or any other client application?

Comment: I am able to hit the endpoint via the browser but the GET_API_URL is just something I created following a tutorial. It's not referenced anywhere but I didn't know if there was a more efficient way to do this.